# tar: A lone zero block at 343398

Tags: tar, extract

while trying to extract a tar.gz file in ubuntu terminal an error happened int he last sentence here it is :
tar: A lone zero block at 343398

what is the solution for this problem???

Answer (score 22):

It depends whether it happens with all `tar.gz` files or just this one. This particular file could be corrupt, and so won't open properly. If using tar to extract, you need to use the `z` option, as that's necessary when an archive is gzipped: `tar xzvf <file.tar.gz>`. Alternatively , it is also worth trying to extract it with `gunzip <file.tar.gz>`

To find out whether the file is corrupt, run `gzip -t <file.tar.gz>`; this command will check the file for errors, and if any are found they should appear in the terminal. This should tell you whether the file is corrupt.

If the file is sound and the error reoccurs, it means it is probably the known issue with tar that occurs when a file does not have a pair of `zero blocks` at the end of it, as GNU tar expects. The solution to this is to add the `-i` option to ignore the `zero blocks`. So use `tar ixzvf <file.tar.gz>` The issue is documented [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21270445) in detail.

Answer (score 2):

The same thing has happened to me because I piped both stdout **and** stderr through a channel that doesn't separate stderr and stdout (an android adb terminal session).

That way some error messages ended up in the stream. This was the faulty command:

- Faulty command, adb shell just merges stderr and stdout locally => garbage! :
  `adb shell tar -cf - /some/dir \| uuencode bla | uudecode  -o - > backup.tar`
- Fixed command:
  `adb shell tar -cf - /some/dir 2>/dev/null\| uuencode bla | uudecode  -o - > backup.tar`

The same will happen if you do a similar command over SSH like this quick tar streaming over ssh if you forget to redirect stderr to /dev/null:

`ssh user@host tar -czf /some/remote/path 2\>/dev/null > /local/path/to/file.tar.gz`

Comment: Good catch. It *also* happens if you set `RequestTTY yes` in your ssh_config. Can be explicitly disabled with `-T      Disable pseudo-tty allocation.` For me, the error was `tar: Skipping to next header` originally, the lone zero block occurred when I tried with `--posix`..

Answer (score 2):

I got this error the other day trying to untar an archive which was not gzipped. The source of the file was unknown to me but I figured that the creator might use `cat` to combine several tars into a single one. This caused the end-of-file zero marker to be read by `tar` utility in the middle of a combined archive thus displaying "A lone zero block" error.

If this is the case then `--ignore-zeros` or `-i` option might help to suppress these errors. Please see `man tar` or [this link](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Ignore-Zeros.html) as a reference.